# Why is WordPress redirecting to localhost

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website running on a server, using a docker container (with port forwarding 8001:80), and an Apache server with proxypass to redirect "demo.travel-itineraries.com" to "localhost:8001".

My problem is that WordPress redirects to localhost instead of using the website URL I specified.

- My WordPress configuration doesn't contain any "localhost" occurrence (I tried `SELECT * from wp_options where option_value like '%localhost%';` and there is no occurrence of localhost)
- The WordPress address is set correctly

[image]

The homepage is working fine (http://demo.travel-itineraries.com/) but the second page isn't. If you check the link in the navbar, it's a link to "http://demo.travel-itineraries.com/les-joyaux-de-ladriatique-a-bord-du-pacific" but WordPress redirects to "http://localhost/les-joyaux-de-ladriatique-a-bord-du-pacific".
I checked with curl, and the RedirectedBy header is set to "WordPress".

Do you have any idea why it keeps redirecting?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Worth a try: There is an extremely old bug in Wordpress which causes problems in permalinks (i.e. pages are not found) after moving the site to another server or directory even though everything is set correctly.

And there's the also-extremely-old fix for it to go to the backend, open the *Settings > Permalinks* page, change any one little detail, change it back again and click "save changes". And I've heard from others that often it's even enough to just open that Permalinks page without changing or saving anything.

I just had that again in the current version (5.8.3) – same problem, same fix. I really wonder why that bug still exisits...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really thought this could work since I'm convinced it could be related to a mysterious cache... but it didn't. I went on the Settings > Permalink then changed multiple things, saved, changed back, saved, and it didn't change. (I also tried in private browsing to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed Yoast is installed, the premium version of that plugin automatically creates redirects, you can check those by going to SEO > Redirects in the back-end.

Comment: I tried to deactivate Yoast plugin and try in private browsing and I get the same result, I think it should have work by deactivating, right?

Comment: Depends if Yoast wrote it to the .htaccess or not, not sure if it will clean that on it's deactivation hook